# Rails 5, Cocoon Gem - nested form inside nested form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I am trying to use cocoon gem to build nested forms.

I have models for Organisation, Package::Bip and Tenor.

The **associations** are:

Organisation

```
has_many :bips, as: :ipable, class_name: Package::Bip
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :bips,  reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Package::Bip (polymorphic)

```
 belongs_to :ipable, :polymorphic => true, optional: true, inverse_of: :bip

  has_one :tenor, as: :tenor
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tenor,  reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Tenor (polymorphic)

```
belongs_to :tenorable, :polymorphic => true, optional: true
```

The **forms** have:

In my organisations/_form.html.erb, I have:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :bips do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>
        <%= render 'package/bips/bip_fields', f: f %>

    <% end %>

    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add another intellectual property resource', f, :bips, partial: 'package/bips/bip_fields' %>
```

In my bip_fields.html.erb nested form, I have:

```
<%# if @package_bips.tenor.blank? %> 
  <%= link_to_add_association 'Add timing', f, :tenor, partial: 'tenors/tenor_fields' %>  
<%# end %>

<%= f.simple_fields_for :tenor do |tenor_form| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= render 'tenors/tenor_fields', f: tenor_form %>
<% end %>
```

**Javascript**

The cocoon docs suggest adding a js file to specify association-insertion-node as a function. In my tenor_subform.js I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add_tenor a").
      data("association-insertion-method", 'append').
      data("association-insertion-node", function(link){
        return link.closest('.row').next('.row').find('.tenor_form')
      });
});
```

**Controllers**

In my organisation controller, I have:

```
def new
    @organisation = Organisation.new
    @organisation.bips
end
```

*Note*: I'm not sure if I need to add another line to my new action to create the organisation.bip.tenor instance. I'm also unsure if im supposed to add has_one through association on the organisation.rb that references the tenor.

```
def organisation_params
      params.fetch(:organisation, {}).permit(:title,  :comment,

          bips_attributes:            [:id, :status,  :_destroy,
            tenor_attributes:           [:id,:commencement, :expiry,                      :_destroy]

        ],
```

In my tenor controller, I have:

```
def tenor_params
      params.require(:tenor).permit( :commencement, :expiry)
    end
```

**ERRORS**

I am not sure if I need to add tenor actions to the organisation controller (the ultimate parent of bip which in turn is the parent of tenor).

When I save all of this and try it, I get an error that says:

```
unknown attribute 'tenor_id' for Tenor.
```

When I see other SO posts with this error, its often because the :id attribute hasn't been whitelisted in the parent class. I have done that.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

**Tenor controller**

```
class TenorsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_tenor, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  # after_action :verify_authorized

  def index
    @tenors = Tenor.all
    # authorize @tenors
  end

    def show

  end

  def new
    @tenor = Tenor.new
    # authorize @tenor
  end

  def edit

  end

  def create
    @tenor = Tenor.new(tenor_params)
    # authorize @tenor

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tenor.save
        format.html { redirect_to @tenor }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tenor }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @tenor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
   respond_to do |format|
      if @tenor.update(tenor_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @tenor }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @tenor }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @tenor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

   def destroy
    @tenor.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to action: :index }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_tenor
      @tenor = Tenor.find(params[:id])
      # authorize @tenor
    end

    def tenor_params
      params.require(:tenor).permit(:express_interest, :commencement, :expiry, :enduring, :repeat, :frequency)
    end

end
```

Comment: The error states you somewhere you are referring to a `tenor_id` for a `Tenor` object. We do not see enough code to see where that is. Your tenor should have a bips_id, but since you have a `has_one` there should not be a `tenor_id` at all?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Tenor is polymorphic, it will hold a bips id. I don't understand the suggestion. Do you mean the ultimate parent (organisation.rb) should also have an association to Tenor?

Comment: I mean: the error says somewhere you are trying to assign a tenor-id, so where in your code/form could that be? Can you show us what is posted to the controller?

Comment: Hmm - I added my tenor controller above. Maybe it's because my organisation controller doesnt have a new action for new tenor (nested through bip). Eg: @organisation.bips.tenor - do I need that to nest once removed?

Comment: You have a single form with nested data, doesn't matter how deep. It is only posted to the one controller: the top level (so organisation). When saving the form, you get an error of an unknown attribute `tenor_id` (on what line?). Rails does not invent data to set, so either the data posted to your controller (and thus the form), contains a field `tenor_id`, and that is why I asked to show us what is posted to the controller (you can find this in your logfile). The tenor controller is not relevant in this case. I would search my code for `tenor_id` and remove it :)

Comment: But do I need to specify an association between organisation and tenor in my organisation.rb (since that is the controller that is the parent/grandparent for the nested forms)?  If I add @organisation.bips.build_tenor to my organisation controller, then I think that also needs a model association to be declared to get it working.

Comment: My app does not make reference to tenor_id anywhere.

Comment: the whitelisted param arrays in organisation and bip include the :id attribute for tenor_attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `has_one` relation is wrongly declared. Because you say `as: :tenor` makes it look for a `tenor_id`.

You have to declare it as follows:

```
has_one :tenor, as: :tenorable
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model does not see the id of `nested_attr.Add :inverse_of => #{model}`.

Example:

```
class Tenor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :traps, :inverse_of => :bips
end
```

For more information look [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) or [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations) documentation.

Comment: But tenor.rb is polymorphic, it has: belongs_to :tenorable, :polymorphic => true, optional: true